# Neural Networks activation function

Tags: machine-learning

The only activation function I have seen for neural networks so far is the logistic function. Are there other functions commonly used? If so, how do you choose the activation function?

Comment: by modelling your domain...

Comment: @MitchWheat What do you mean exactly?

Comment: as mentioned below: "Selection depends on the problem."

Comment: given a problem, how do you decide which activation function to try?

Comment: comment 1 is useless for me since I don't see what you mean by choosing the activation function "by modelling your domain..." Could you be a bit more specific?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeap there are:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function

Selection depends on the problem.

Comment: I see. I read that the sigmoid activation function is more similar to biological systems. Do you have examples where to use other functions is more natural or efficient?

Answer (score 1):

Hyperbolic Tangent function is another widely used activation function for neural network.  The hyperbolic tangent function will produce positive numbers between -1 and 1.  Because the hyperbolic tangent activation function has a derivative, it can be used with gradient descent based training methods.

You can also use your own custom activation function but you need to design your own cost function. For novice, it is better you follow the literature.

Comment: tanh is just a rescaled version of the logistic function. It is useful when you need values from -1 to 1. Not sure if it was what you meant to imply but having a derivative is not the difference.